# Unable to store the response of a POST method

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am able to console.log the response of a POST method.
But I want to store this response in a variable to use it further in the code.
Please help.

post method call sends an object as response.

student.ts (the Student is a class which is same as the object received from the post request.)

```
export class Student {
ID : number;
firstName : string;
}
```

component.ts (on submit method is called on submitting a form. this.student gives output as undefined)

```
public student : Student[];

onSubmit() {
    this._studentService.addData(this.addStudentForm.value)
      .subscribe( response => console.log("respnse", response),
        );
    console.log(this.student);
  }
```

service.ts

```
addData(studentData) : Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(this._url, studentData);
  }
```

When i try to store the response into a variable i am getting output as undefined.
How can i store the response in a variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just add `this.student = response;` inside subscribe:

```
this._studentService.addData(this.addStudentForm.value).subscribe( response => {
    console.log("respnse", response);
    this.student = response;
});
```

But if you want do something with `student` you should do this inside `next` callback of subscribe:

```
this._studentService.addData(this.addStudentForm.value).subscribe( response => {
    console.log("respnse", response);
    this.student = response;
    console.log(this.student) <- THIS WILL WORK - STUDENT IS NOT UNDEFINED
    // HERE ARE YOUR METHODS WHICH ARE USING STUDENT
});
```

This `console.log` after subsrciption still will be undefined, because this code will be executed BEFORE subscription is ended, so `student` is `undefinded` for this moment.

Comment: Though this will add response to `this.student`, please explain to the OP why `console.log(this.student)` will still be `undeined`

Comment: @jasmin i've added an explanation to my answer, check it

Comment: oh @yasmin is not assigning value to student property

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public responseData:any; 
public onSubmit() {
  this._studentService.addData(this.addStudentForm.value).subscribe((response:any)=> { 
    console.log("success: ", JSON.stringify(response)); 
    this.responseData = response; 
  }, (error:any){
    console.log("error: ", JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}
```

Comment: what you can see in developer console?

Comment: I get the success and response {"firstName":"qwert","lastName":"qwerf","dateOfBirth":"2019-04-24T20:00:00.000Z"}
@Khurshid i am new to angular and hence i dint knew the scope of the response received was limited to subscribe. So that was my main question.